# Filling out a matrix in python using a for loop

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm trying to convert some MATLAB code to python but I'm stuck on this for loop to fill out a matrix.  Here is the MATLAB

```
for t=0:(Num-1)
  for j= 1:2
      ExpD(j,j) = exp(V(j,j)*t*Step)
  end
  Output(:,t+1) = V*expD
end
```

And here is my attempt at the python

```
    for t in range(0,Num-1):
        for j in range(1,2):
            ExpD[j,j]=ma.exp(D[j,j[*t*Step)
        Output[:,t+1] = V*expD
```

I'm getting an error saying there are too many indices for the array though.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: you probably need to preallocate them (as you should in MATLAB too....) . Use `np.zeros` to make a zeroed `ExpD` and `Output` matrix of the correct size.

Comment: `V*expD` is a matrix multiplication in MATLAB, but an element-wise multiplication in Python. But we don’t don’t the sizes of thede arrays, so can’t know for sure how to fix this. Please read [mre], without it we can never be sure what you’re doing.

Comment: Also copy-paste the full error message, don’t paraphrase error messages, they become a lot less informative that way.

Comment: MATLAB lets you 'cheat' by defining and growing a matrix by simply assigning values.  `numpy` does not.  `Exp0` has to be created first, with the full desired size.  Also what `j](t*Step` supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check `for j in range(1,2)` is correct. You might want `range(1,3)`.